# Где выделяется память под переменные в JS

Tags: javascript

Часть кода на js по реализации связного списка.
 Не понятно в каком месте выделяется память под переменную node.
 Пытаюсь провести аналогию с C/C++. Там понятно - вот тебе выделение памяти в куче, вот тебе на стеке, c js не понятно и второй вопрос: создаем объект через new, ясно что поля объекта описываются через this как в коде ниже, но что если внутри функции LinkedList() создать что то вроде

```
var length = 0
var head = null
var Node = function(element){
          this.element = element; 
          this.next = null; 
      };
```

Все так же прекрасно работает с заменой в коде this.length на length и так же со всеми остальным,но при этом создать объект,скажем такой

```
var obj = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 25,
    var test
}
```

в которым бы фигурировала переменная var test мы не можем, а запись

```
var list = new LinkedList()
```

именно и создает нам объект с описанными полями,так что тогда происходит с

```
var length = 0
var head = null
var Node = ...
```

Так вот,где в такой случае выделиться память под length,head и Node и почему все таки это работает.

```
function LinkedList() {
      this.length = 0; 
      this.head = null; 
      this.Node = function(element){
          this.element = element; 
          this.next = null; 
      }; 

      this.get_size = () => this.length;
      this.get_head = () => this.head;

      this.add = function(element){

        //в каком месте выделяется память под переменную node?
        var node = new this.Node(element);

        if(this.head === null){
            this.head = node;
        } else  {
            var currentNode = this.head;

            while(currentNode.next){
                currentNode  = currentNode.next;
            }

            currentNode.next = node;
        }

        this.length++;
      }; 
...
}

var list = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: память выделяется при создании объекта и очищается, если нет ссылок на объект, либо он больше не нужен (example: `var a = 'asd'` - выделяется память под строку и т.д.), управлять памятью напрямую вы не можете, js - высокоуровневый язык, это вам не С, где вы могли бы использовать `malloc()` или `free()`, да и на моей практике ниразу не возникала проблема с памятью, хотя есть сайты высоконагруженные, всё работает чётко, так же можете прочитать про [принцип достижимости javascript](https://javascript.info/garbage-collection)

Comment: Хорошо, тогда второй вопрос: почему при создании объекта через new , если мы объявим внутри функции переменную var length то все работает хорошо? Ведь вот функция var list = new LinkedList() отработала - вернула нам объект и кажется что ссылка на  length пропала, но нет, если мы создаем добавляем элементы в список то значение length увеличивается, хочется предполагать что length становиться в этом случае глобальной переменной,так ли это?

Comment: ссылка на `length` не пропала, у вас переменная `list` - объект класса `LinkedList()` и пока `list` не присвоят что-то другое, либо он пропадёт с области видимости - память будет забита (`var list` - глобальный объект)

Comment: и соответственно поскольку ```list``` это объект класса то при объявлении внутри 
```LinkedList()``` ````var length```` ошибки нет,верно ? Ведь через ```new``` нам возвращается Объект а внутри объекта мы не можем объявлять ```var length```

Comment: почему не можете объявлять внутри объекта `var length`? это обычная функция

Comment: В стандарте js про место выделения памяти ничего нет. Если уж очень хочется, то смотреть надо на конкретные реализации. А видимость переменных определяется замыканиями, а не памятью. https://learn.javascript.ru/closure

Comment: Если проводить аналогию с С++, то все переменные и поля в js - это объекты с автоматическим хранением (при этом отсутствует прямая привязка к области видимости). В первом примере вы присваиваете `Node` ссылку на объект - функцию (которая при этом не вызывается).

Comment: Окей, понял, почитаю про замыкания, спасибо

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо,разобрался,материал помог